# Convert date to only month from the given date field

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-formatting

I would like to convert one of my date column to just month

I have columns values as

example :

```
select datecolumn from abc
```

datecolumn

```
jan-20
feb-20
mar-20
apr-20
```

I would like to get only month in the form

```
01
02
03
04
```

Comment: Please check [datepart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Is that column of a `date`-like datatype, or it's a string?

Comment: That isnt a `date`, that's clearly a `varchar`. You should really fix the data type, them you can use things like `DATEPART`.

Comment: 20 years after Y2K and people are STILL making this basic mistake!

Answer (score 1):

I would use either `MONTH` or `DATEPART` functions

```
SELECT DATEPART(month, '2014/04/28');
```

Result: 4

Answer (score 0):

The data types are not correct.  But you can create a new column with the format you want:

```
alter table t
    add datecol_mmmyy as (left(datename(month, datecol), 3) +'-' + datename(year, datecol));
```

Then you can refer to `datecol_mmmyy` and get the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Untested and quite sketchy but this could work:

```
select case when datecolumn like 'Jan%' then '01'
when datecolumn like 'Feb%' then '02'
when datecolumn like 'Mar%' then '03'
when datecolumn like 'Apr%' then '04'
when datecolumn like 'May%' then '05'
when datecolumn like 'Jun%' then '06'
when datecolumn like 'Jul%' then '07'
when datecolumn like 'Aug%' then '08'
when datecolumn like 'Sep%' then '09'
when datecolumn like 'Oct%' then '10'
when datecolumn like 'Nov%' then '11'
when datecolumn like 'Dec%' then '12'
end as datecolumn 
from abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a '01-' to the beginning of the field and then use DATEPART function:

```
DECLARE @Month char(10) = 'Feb-20'
select DATEPART(MM,'01-'+@Month)
```

If you want the output in two characters, then you can use the format funtion:

```
DECLARE @Month char(10) = 'Feb-20'
select FORMAT(DATEPART(MM,'01-'+@Month),'00')
```

Hope this helps.